# USB wont load boot menu ubuntu

Tags: boot, usb, menu

Just installed ubuntu and am having problems, can't update anything and am stuck in terminal, so I need to reinstall. Bios is still set to boot from USB but the same USB has been in my cpu and will no longer load boot menu. Can someone please help, been trying to get linux working for a few days now.

Comment: Apart from **F2** button which enters to **BIOS** settings, there is one more button which shows the boot devices at the beginning. After pressing it while your system starts, It will show you the list from which you can boot your OS. The key would be any of these buttons.. **F10**, **F11** or **F12** Just give it a try while you connected to USB. Reply..

Comment: which pc did you are using.If you are using lenovo laptop there was a special nova button(near power cable jack) was present to boot into bios.